# Java URL with relative address

Tags: java, url, relative-path

Quick question:

For some initiations I need to pass java URL class with url to specific file. But I posses this file in resources in my aplication. So I ask is there possible to create java URL class with relative address? I have never seen something like that, so I wonder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a `File` object first (where you can provide a relative path to your resource) and then convert it to an URL:

```
File file = new File("resources/myresource.abc");
URL url = file.toUrl();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a URL relative to where the your java class file is and refernce files in the same location. This is done using the the [getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) method of class. Place the resource in a folder called "resources" in the same position as your .class file. Then you can get a url relative to the position of the class like this:

```
URL url = <InsertYourClassName>.class.getResource("resources/<InsertNameOfResource>");
```

This will get a url path relative to where you class is and look in the resources folder for your resource. The same can be achieved by just placing the resource in the same directory as your class but not in a resources folder like this:

```
URL url = <InsertYourClassName>.class.getResource("<InsertNameOfResource>");
```

Hope this helps :)